# IP Groups of whitelisting frontend - Træfik

Tags: ip, docker-swarm, traefik

Is it possible to create ip groups in some way? so I can provide træfik with something like this: `traefik.frontend.whiteList.sourceRange=MyGroup`.

I would love to not worry about which ips I give access to when deploying a new service, but rather just provide a group and know that someone else is in control of managing the list of that group.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a source range in [CIDR notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing). To whitelist all local network IPs from 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.255.255, for example:

```
traefik.frontend.whiteList.sourceRange=192.168.0.0/16
```

Here's a handy helper for getting the right notation: [CIDR Calculator](http://www.subnet-calculator.com/cidr.php)

If you want to whitelist single IPs only, you can use a comma separated list, limiting the range to a single IP address with `/32`:

```
traefik.frontend.whiteList.sourceRange=1.2.3.4/32,2.3.4.5/32
```